# Ajax json cross domain request not working with cordova app

Tags: android, jquery, json, ajax, cordova

I am doing cordova android app. In this I want user login functionality which is authenticated by REST api. But in mobile device it is giving ajax error code '0' and thrownError blank. I have attached my device with the desktop system for testing the app.

While in desktop browser it is working fine.
I have used the below code,

```
apiurl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/restapi/"; 
$.ajax({
                url: apiurl+'user-signin/login',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType :'json'
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend:function(){ $.mobile.loading( 'show' ); },
                complete: function() { $.mobile.loading( 'hide' )  }, 
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res.status);
                    if(res.status == "success") {
                        goInsert(res.result.user_id, res.result.user_name, res.result.user_password);
                        window.location="dashboard.html";
                    } else if(res.status == "failed") {
                        alert(res.msg);
                        //alert(message[res.msg]);
                    } 
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status+":"+textStatus+":"+thrownError);
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                },
                data: new FormData($('#loginfrm')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false

            });
```

I have added the "header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); " in my rest api.

I have also used the datatype "jsonp", but it also not working for me.

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova 5 then you will likely need to look at your Content Security Policy which is a meta tag in your index.html - by default it's not going to allow this unless you amend it to include your API's URL.

Try modifying the meta tag (or add one if not present) to look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/">
```

For a deeper dive into this check out http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/

Comment: Hi, It is giving 'Error Loading Page' in app when form submitted.